# pam_tally2 locking everyone out after configuring common-auth file on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, users, user-management, pam

I am trying to configure user lockout after 3 unsuccessful attempt. I found instructions on the internet but I always end up with the same problem: after modifying `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` to include the user lockout settings, EVERYTHING gets locked out for good and the only way to fix this is to plug the drive containing Ubuntu into another Linux machine, open the file and remove the pam_tally2 config.

These are the settings I'm using:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [default=bad success=ok]        pam_tally2.so  deny=3 unlock_time=1200
```

Can somebody help, please?

Comment: I have no direct experience to offer, but I *think* you also need to add a line to the `common-account` file in order to decrement the tally on success - see for example [Why does this PAM code prevent all logins to a Debian system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562703/65304)

Comment: Alright, I put the pam_tally2.so line (the second one in my original post) and it worked, but only if 'unlock_time=1200' is kept. If I remove it (to make this an indefinite lockout) everybody, even admins, gets locked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steeldriver was right! For future reference:

1. Put the following line in **/etc/pam.d/common-auth**:

`auth    required   pam_tally2.so  deny=3 unlock_time=1200`

**Note:** it has to be placed FIRST, right before `auth [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok`

2. Put the following line: `account required        pam_tally2.so` in **/etc/pam.d/common-account**

This should be done in order to avoid getting locked out of the entire system (all users, even root!) for good.